# run picoC non-recursively as an iterated function

Tags: c, recursion, interpreter, iteration

I've been playing around with a few C interpreters and have found
picoC to look like it meets all my needs.

to kick off a script you call
void PicocCallMain(int argc, char **argv); which recursively calls the internal
parser etc..

Is it possible to recode picoC so that I could run scripts iteratively.

for example.

```
while(1)
 {
 picoCyield(&script1);
 picoCyield(&script2);
 }
```

each call to picoCyield would call the token reader no more than required to
execute the smallest possible block of script.

I could run picoC as is with threads, but I the enviorment I am working in
prohibits it..

Any help, or pointers to a similair interpreter that can do this, would
be greatly appreciated.

Comment: off topic: i just did a search for picoc iteratively: .. google's already indexed my question.. ( not bad ! ). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583494/run-picoc-non-recursively-as-an-interated-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the top-level code for interactive mode.   Where it currently prints the prompt and waits for input, I would replace with a callback to your program which you would use to provide the next statement.   Then all the line-by-line execution is already done for you.